# Prevent a plot to be overwrite in a for loop

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to create three different plots in a for loop and then plotting them together in the same graph. 
I know that some questions regarding this topic have already been asked. But I do not know what I am doing wrong. Why is my plot being overwritten.
Nevertheless, I tried both solutions (creating a list or using assign function) and I do not know why I get my plot overwriten at the end of the loop.

So, the first solution is to create a list:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

out<-list()
for (i in c(1,2,4)){
  print(i)
  name= paste("WT.1",colnames(WT.1@meta.data[i]), sep=" ")
  print(name)
  out[[length(out) + 1]] <- qplot(NEW.1@meta.data[i],
                 geom="density",
                 main= name)
  print(out[[i]])
}
grid.arrange(out[[1]], out[[2]], out[[3]], nrow = 2)
```

When I print the plot inside the loop, I get what I want...but of course they are not together.

[First Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywvxt.png)

When I plot them all together at the end, I get the same plot for all of the three: the last Plot I did.

[All together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhqsm.png)

This is the second option: assign function. I have exactly the same problem.

```
for ( i in c(1,2,4)) {
  assign(paste("WT.1",colnames(WT.1@meta.data[i]),sep="."), 
     qplot(NEW.1@meta.data[i],geom="density",
           main=paste0("WT.1",colnames(WT.1@meta.data[i]))))
 }
```

Comment: Please read up on providing a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so it's easier for other users to assist you.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing to `dev.off` inside the loop for every iteration. Reproducible code below:

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

out<-list()
for (i in c(1,2,3)){
  print(i)

  out[[i]] <- qplot(1:100, rnorm(100), colour = runif(100))

  print(out[[i]])
  dev.off()
}
grid.arrange(out[[1]], out[[2]], out[[3]], nrow = 2)
```

[image]